# possible to print created filter for rethinkdb for debugging purposes?

Tags: rethinkdb

Using node I'm trying to programmatically creating a filter which fails. Is there a way to check the output of a filter as it is passed to RethinkDB? That way I can try to debug the filter.

**Background**
I'm trying to write a helper that, given nested object notation `a.b` matches against a given value.

E.g.: I'm trying to create the following filter:

`entry("a")("b").match(val)`

Using the helper:

```
  function iterateProp(entry, path, val) {
    if (path.length) {
      var propKey = path.shift();
      return iterateProp(entry(propKey), path, val);
    }
    return entry(val);
  }
```

Called as such:

```
    Model.filter(function(entry) {
        var modelKey = "a.b"; //illustrational
        var val ="someValToMatch"; //illustrational
        var filter = iterateProp(entry, modelKey.split("."), val);
        console.log("filter", filter); //HOW TO DISPLAY FILTER AS CONSTRUCTED BY RETHINKDB DRIVER AND SEND TO RETHINKDB?
        return filter;
    })
```

This should just work in my book, but it doesn't. So how to display the constructed filter so I can do some debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `toString()` at the end of the query (replacing `run()`) to see what the driver will send to the server.

```
console.log(r.table("test").filter(...).toString())
```